# Attaching timing belt pulley

Tags: gears

In the picture below, the stepper motors are fixed to stay in place. They have small pulleys that rotate the bigger pulleys. If building such a system, how should the bigger pulley be attached?

Looking at the image it seems the smaller U-shaped piece where the camera is mounted is fixed to the bigger pulley. This is simple with some screws but how is the pulley connected to the frame? Does the same method apply to the other side?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In some ways this arrangement isn't completely ideal because you are potentially putting a significant bending moment on the bearings which support the larger pulleys especially in the lower, horizontal pulley.

Ideally you would have the driven pulleys mounted in a Y shaped yoke with a bearing on each arm and the shaft fixed to the pulley and the frame element it is driving.

It is possible that the short cylindrical elements (most visible in the top right) are bearing/housing units but they could just be spacers.

Having said that this isn't necessarily a real problem in this sort of application as long as the frame is stiff enough and the loads on the bearings are within acceptable limits.

In this design it looks like the moving parts of the frame are fixed directly to the bosses on the pulleys with set screws with bearings on the opposite end of the shaft only. It's not clear if these are moving element bearings or just plain bushings.